# Procedure too large - Excel VBA MAcro

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the below code so whenever the Enduser choose the week from a dropdown menu in another sheet it will update go to the column of this week in the RawData and update the figures, but it seems that I did something very stupid, and it could be done using different way :(

The below is the code

```
Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String

QuestionToMessageBox = "Confirmation Required"

YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Please confirm updating the results for " & Range("F13").Value & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation Required")

If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then

Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView").Activate

If Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("F13").Value = "Week 01" Then

Worksheets("RawData").Activate

With Sheets("RawData")

Sheets("RawData").Range("B2:B14").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J40:J52").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B16").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J55").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B19:B28").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J58:J67").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B32:B41").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J71:J80").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B45:B54").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J84:J93").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B58").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J97").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B59").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J98").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B62:B71").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J101:J110").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B75:B84").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J114:J123").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("B88:B97").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J127:J136").Value

End With

Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView").Activate

Else

If Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("F13").Value = "Week 02" Then

Worksheets("RawData").Activate

With Sheets("RawData")

Sheets("RawData").Range("C2:C14").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J40:J52").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C16").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J55").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C19:C28").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J58:J67").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C32:C41").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J71:J80").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C45:C54").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J84:J93").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C58").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J97").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C59").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J98").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C62:C71").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J101:J110").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C75:C84").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J114:J123").Value
Sheets("RawData").Range("C88:C97").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J127:J136").Value

End With

Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView").Activate
'--------
Else

If Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("F13").Value = "Week 03" Then

Worksheets("RawData").Activate

With Sheets("RawData")

    Sheets("RawData").Range("D2:D14").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J40:J52").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D16").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J55").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D19:D28").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J58:J67").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D32:D41").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J71:J80").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D45:D54").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J84:J93").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D58").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J97").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D59").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J98").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D62:D71").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J101:J110").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D75:D84").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J114:J123").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Range("D88:D97").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J127:J136").Value

End With

Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView").Activate


'__________

Else

If Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("F13").Value = "Week 04" Then

    Worksheets("RawData").Activate

    With Sheets("RawData")

        Sheets("RawData").Range("E2:E14").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J40:J52").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E16").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J55").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E19:E28").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J58:J67").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E32:E41").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J71:J80").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E45:E54").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J84:J93").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E58").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J97").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E59").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J98").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E62:E71").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J101:J110").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E75:E84").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J114:J123").Value
        Sheets("RawData").Range("E88:E97").Value = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("J127:J136").Value

    End With

    Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView").Activate
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? You didn't ask one. Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) Try to provide a [mcve] of your actual issue.

Comment: Are you getting the actual error message that your procedure is too large?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/983044/-compile-error-procedure-too-large-error-message-when-you-try-to-run-a  If not, then as @Peh said....

Comment: I am getting the error "Procedure too Large", because I am reapeating the same code 52 times " one for each week" , and I'd really appreciate it your help if there is any workaround or another way to write the code for the below.

Answer (score 1):

Try to structure your code without repeating things that are always the same. One possible solution could be the following (using select case and a variable for the target column):

```
Sub Update()
Dim RawDataSheet As Worksheet, ResUpdSheet As Worksheet, Col As String
Set RawDataSheet = Sheets("RawData")
Set ResUpdSheet = Sheets("ResultsUpdateView")

    If MsgBox("Please confirm updating the results for " & Range("F13").Value & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation Required") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Select Case ResUpdSheet.Range("F13").Value
        Case "Week 01"
            Col = "B"
        Case "Week 02"
            Col = "C"
        Case "Week 03"
            Col = "D"
        Case "Week 04"
            Col = "E"
        Case Else
        '...
    End Select

    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "2:" & Col & "14").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J40:J52").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "16").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J55").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "19:" & Col & "28").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J58:J67").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "32:" & Col & "41").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J71:J80").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "45:" & Col & "54").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J84:J93").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "58").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J97").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "59").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J98").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "62:" & Col & "71").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J101:J110").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "75:" & Col & "84").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J114:J123").Value
    RawDataSheet.Range(Col & "88:" & Col & "97").Value = ResUpdSheet.Range("J127:J136").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jochen for your effort, I've tried the above solution, and didnt work, it didnt check the week selected from the dropdown menu, and it returned the values to everyweek cells in the RawData Sheet

Comment: Please check the dropdown in your sheet, especially the LinkedCell to see where the box puts the selected value. Change the `select case` statement correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.
You can extract the week number from cell F13 and use that as a base for your column number (week 1 is column B, week 2 is column C).

`colNum = CLng(Replace(Sheets("ResultsUpdateView").Range("F13"), "Week ", "")) + 1` will convert your week number to a `Long` data type and add 1 to get the column number.  This can then be used to reference a cell:  `Sheets("RawData").Cells(16, colNum)` being row 16 on the column identified by `colNum`.

This code will take the value from cell F13 and use that to place the values in the correct column (code's untested):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim colNum As Long

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ResultsUpdateView")
    colNum = CLng(Replace(wrkSht.Range("F13"), "Week ", "")) + 1 'Get the week number from cell F13 & add 1.

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")
        .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(14, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J40:J52").Value
        .Cells(16, colNum).Value = wrkSht.Range("J55").Value
        .Range(.Cells(19, colNum), .Cells(28, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J58:J67").Value
        .Range(.Cells(32, colNum), .Cells(41, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J71:J80").Value
        .Range(.Cells(45, colNum), .Cells(54, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J84:J93").Value
        .Cells(58, colNum).Value = wrkSht.Range("J97").Value
        .Cells(59, colNum).Value = wrkSht.Range("J98").Value
        .Range(.Cells(62, colNum), .Cells(71, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J101:J110").Value
        .Range(.Cells(75, colNum), .Cells(84, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J114:J123").Value
        .Range(.Cells(88, colNum), .Cells(97, colNum)).Value = wrkSht.Range("J127:J136").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Darren, thing is there is a dropdown menu in another sheet with a list of weeks (Week 01, Week 02, Week 03 ...etc), the user select the week in this sheet, then update the figures in the same sheet and click update, once he clicked I want the macro to take the figures he entered in the results update sheet --> go to the RawData sheet find the relevant cell for the week, and paste the value to the RawData Sheet

Comment: It should work.  Range `F13` on the `ResultsUpdateView` contains the drop-down menu by the looks of your code.  So the user updates this figure from the drop-down menu, updates the figures in the same sheet and presses the _Updatedate_ button.  The code looks at the week that was selected in F13 and uses that to find the correct column.

Comment: I've tried to test the code and its not working, Darren, thing is there is already a sheet with the 52 Columns (RawData) Sheet and the header of the columns are the same as the list in the dropdown menu mentioned earlier. 

in your code I think there is an increment to add another column (+1), I want the macro to find the column with the same header as the value in the DropDown menu.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question then as it's working perfectly the way I envision it.  To test I created a new blank worksheet and added two sheets - the first called _RawData_ and the second _ResultsUpdateView_.  I added some test data in column `J` of _ResultsUpdateView_ (I used `=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` which would give me the cell address and copied/pasted values).  Cell F13 I set up with _Data Validation_ to allow a _List_ with the source `Week 01, Week 02, Week 03, Week 04`.  I selected `Week 04` and ran my code - data was transferred from column `J` to column `E` on `RawData`.

Comment: I selected `Week 02` and data was transferred from column `J` on `ResultsUpdateView` to column `B` on RawData.  I then compared to the output from your code - had to sort out the `IF....END IF` block first though and it returned _exactly_ the same result.

Comment: There isn't any increment to add another column.  The +1 is there as the data needs placing in a column number one higher than the selected week number.  If you select `Week 1` the data is placed in column B - which is column 2.  If you select `Week 52` you'll want the data in column `BA` which is column number 53.